# Is there a distance at which the Kerr metric looks like the Schwarzschild metric?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, approximations, kerr-metric

As the title says: Is there a distance at which the Kerr metric looks like Schwarzschild metric?

Edit: if there isn't any such distance (smaller than infinity), can we measure from the outside, with which speed a black hole rotates?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric#Kerr–Schild_coordinates): “At large distances from the source (R ≫ a), these equations reduce to the Eddington–Finkelstein form of the Schwarzschild metric.”

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151658/discussion-on-question-by-martymcfly-is-there-a-distance-at-which-the-kerr-metri); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4):

The Kerr and Schwarzschild metrics are different at all distances from a black hole, and both approach flat Minkowski spacetime at infinite radius.

Measurements of black hole spin are done by observing effects (e.g. accretion disc motion) *close* to the black hole.